# My 2008 Honda Fit can't use synthetic oil

Tags: engine, honda, oil, fit

I have a 2008 Honda Fit and in the manual says "Honda doesn't recommend using synthetic oil".

I want to know why, as I can't find the answer online. Seems like any car can use synthetic, why mine says it shouldn't?

I'm using a semi synthetic by Shell as recommended by my mechanic, but I think I will switch to mineral by Honda next change.

Comment: WE DON'T RECOMMEND synthetic oil for use in our engines.
DO NOT USE synthetic oils in our engines.
These 2 statements above mean different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That statement "usually" means that they have not chosen a preferred supplier...

I used a top quality fully synthetic oil in a diesel that had a turbo added and it was fine, the engine, did not have a synthetic specified either, especially as it came from a Nissan and was fitted into a Volvo...

If the synthetic matches , or exceeds, the specifications for the engine then it should be fine.

Comment: The last sentence says it all. If the oil meets or exceeds the API service and Group specifications from the manufacturer you should be OK. I have no idea why they would recommend dino oil exclusively.